# Windows 10 internet significantly slower than Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, internet, speed

I seem to be having the opposite problem to most people.
Yesterday I switched from Ubuntu 16.04 to Windows 10 Home. I downloaded Steam and started downloading some games. My download speed peaked at 706KB/s, but when I was on Ubuntu, I would be getting at least 2.0MB/s (That's good where I live). It's frustrating when it actually takes time to download a 4MB file.

Does anyone know what I can do? (My Motherboard has an Intel I219-V)

I have tried

-Disabling Peer-to-Peer Updating

-Uninstalling OneNote

-Disabling Auto-Tuning

-Disabling LSO

-Updating my drivers

But still no luck. Is there anything else I can do to speed things up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Windows 10 has a number of Live Tiles, such as *Bing News*, which take up bandwidth. Right-click on the app and disable Live Tile or uninstall the app (not possible on some).
2. Check privacy settings... MS Windows 10 maintains a steady stream of chatter regarding searches (*Cortana*), performance etc. You can turn some of these off by pressing <kbd>Windows</kbd>, typing "priva" and selecting *Privacy* settings. For a more complete job, try a third-party tool such as [O&O *ShutUp10*](https://www.oo-software.com/en/shutup10).
3. Check that there are no pending Windows Updates, which will slow things down while completing.
4. Check if something else is eating up bandwidth. Use a tool such as a network sniffer or bandwidth monitor, e.g. *WireShark* or [*Glasswire*, shown below](https://www.glasswire.com/).

[Windows *Task Manager*. on the  *App History* tab, shows accumulated network usage - but *only for Metro apps*.]

[image: Glasswire monitoring badwidth]

Comment: Cheers, mate. I tried the things that you suggested, and I got my speed up to a megabyte per second, which is still below what I feel that I should be getting, but is more than bearable. Until now I had never realized how much of my bandwidth and overall network power was being used by Windows itself. That Glasswire program is pretty helpful. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad it helped, though just a bit. BTW, Windows *Task Manager* , *App History/ tab, shows accumulated network usage - but only for Metro apps.